# Folder structure for AngularJs /NodeJs/Postgresql

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql

How to setup the project with nodejs and angularjs
I am using the following things in my project.

1. Backend - Nodejs & Express
2. Frontend - Html5,Bootstrap,AngularJs
3. Database - Postgresql.

How to setup the project in separate folder like client and server?

Becuase I have MVC for both frontend and backend also. so how could i separate the controllers , models in both(frontend and backend)?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this one

```
├── client
│   ├── app                 - All of our app specific components go in here
│   ├── assets              - Custom assets: fonts, images, etc… 
│   ├── components          - Our reusable components, non-specific to to our app
│ 
├── e2e                     - Our protractor end to end tests
│
└── server
    ├── api                 - Our apps server api
    ├── auth                - For handling authentication with different auth strategies
    ├── components          - Our reusable or app-wide components
    ├── config              - Where we do the bulk of our apps configuration
    │   └── local.env.js    - Keep our environment variables out of source control.
    │   └── environment     - Configuration specific to the environment the server is being run in
    └── views               - Server rendered views
```

taken from here http://tylerhenkel.com/building-an-angular-node-comment-app-using-yeoman/